# Start a Stored Procedure only when I have all the required tables for it

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a one time-monthly JOB with 3 steps, each runs a different SP, how can I get the 1st SP only to start running when I have all the information required ?

ie: I require Table A and Table B information to run SP1 before it goes to step 2 and 3 of the JOB, how do I tell that to the program?

Answer (score 0):

before the execute statement add a check for Table A and Table B. Like this

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tableA) AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB)
BEGIN

 EXEC YourProcedure

END
```

If you want to run the Execute only if both tables exist in the database try this

```
DECLARE @Cnt INT = 0
SELECT @Cnt COUNT(1) FROM sys.objects WHERE Object_Id = OBJECT_ID('tableA')OR Object_Id = OBJECT_ID('tableB')
IF ISNULL(@Cnt,0)=2
        BEGIN

         EXEC YourProcedure

        END
```

or If you want to loop it till the tables are created, then try this

```
    DECLARE @Cnt INT = 0

WHILE ISNULL(@Cnt,0) <2
BEGIN    

SELECT @Cnt COUNT(1) FROM sys.objects WHERE Object_Id = OBJECT_ID('tableA')OR Object_Id = OBJECT_ID('tableB')

IF ISNULL(@Cnt,0)=2
            BEGIN

             EXEC YourProcedure

            END
END
```

If you want to run the Procedure at a specific time. Then Probably you can **schedule it for that particular time in the SQL Job or SSIS Package**. Or If you want to do that check in the SQL Script (*Not Recommended*) Then try this

```
WHILE(1)
BEGIN
  IF(SELECT 1 WHERE GETDATE() = 'dd/mm/yyy hh:ss:mm')
  BEGIN
     EXEC YourProcedure
  END
END
```

Comment: In case the tables don't exist can I loop the JOB till they do?

Comment: I have updated the answer as per your requirements. But when looping till the tables are created, it's recommended to loop only till a specific number in order to avoid deadlocks

Comment: Don't like the first suggestion.   It'll fail to execute if neither table exists.

Comment: The tables exists already in the DB, what I want is to start the SP when they meet a specific datetime, is that possible?

Comment: Yes, Give the condition in the While loop of If statement